# Can an NFC device invoke Android google play to install automatically an application?

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc, bluetooth-lowenergy

Or in more general:
How can I invoke an application download/installation in Android as a result of putting an external NFC/Bluetooth/BLE device near a phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Bluetooth, but if you are using an NFC tag, you can encode an URL there to the app in Google Play so the user can download it. I think it is not possible to download it without user intervention.

Comment: Correct. It's not possible to automatically **start** the installation. (If that was possible it would be a severe security issue.)

Comment: But it is possible to pop up a download request? I have no intention to hack any user...

Comment: Yes - if you embed in the NFC tag a link to the app in Google Play, the user just needs to accept the app installation, with the extra benefit that he/she will see that it comes from a trusted party (the Google Play Store).